# error displaying values got from an array

Tags: php, jquery

I have a database table from which i am getting values and displaying it in a view page.Then the admin will click on the checkbox next to each row in the table.On click of each checkbox i will get the  value of that checkbox.the code(view file and js) for it is this one

view file:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options" id="options" value="<?php echo $row->slNo?>">
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" name="selectAll" />
```

js:

```
$('#selectAll').change(function(){
           if($(this).attr('checked'))
       {
        $('[name=options]').attr('checked',true);
        function updateTextArea() 
        {         
              var allVals = $('#rrol :checked').map(function()
            {
                   return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                $('#getrolevalues').val(allVals);
        }
        $(function() 
        {
             $('#rrol input').click(updateTextArea);
                 updateTextArea();
             });
        }
        else 
        {
             $('[name=options]').attr('checked',false);  
             function updateTextArea() 
             {         
             var allVals = $('#rrol :checked').map(function() 
                     {
                  return $(this).val();
              }).get();
              $('#getrolevalues').val(allVals);
         }
         $(function() 
         {
            $('#rrol input').click(updateTextArea);
            updateTextArea();
          });

          }
});
```

I have saved the values that i got in a hidden text box and im sending it to the controller.code( view file and js) for it is below

view file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="getrolevalues">
```

js:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

          var js=$('#getrolevalues').val();
      $.post(url+"/roles/tabledata",{"gotoption":js},function(data){
          $('#roleschk').html(data.result);

},"json");
```

so far everything is working fine.but after sending the values which i have stored in an array im getting an error.i.e in controller i get the array values and then i use explode function to separate each value.then i use for loop to send those values to model and get the values and display the result.the code is below

controller:

```
function tabledata()
    {
         echo $data=$this->input->post('gotoption');
         $pieces = explode( ",", $data);
        //echo $pieces[1];
        //echo $e=count($pieces);
        $sql=array();
    for($i = 0; $i< count($pieces); $i++)
    { 
        $piec= $pieces[$i];
        $sql[]=$this->rolesmodel->roleselect($piec);
    }
    $sql['dipl']=$sql;

        $slr=$this->load->view('roleschecked',$sql,true);
        $value=array(
            'result'=>$slr
        );
        echo json_encode($value);
}
```

model:

```
function roleselect($piec)
    {
        /*for($i = 0; $i< count($pieces); $i++)
        { */
        echo $chkroles="SELECT * FROM dummyroles WHERE slNo='$piec'";

        $qry=$this->db->query($chkroles);
//      }

        return $qry;
    }
```

also the roleschecked view file where i display the results:

```
<p>You Have selected the following persons</p>
<table border=2>
<tr>
<th>Sl.No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roles</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($dipl as $row)
{?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row()->slNo[0]?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

the problem now is that only last value i get when i use like this in controller

```
.........
.........
$sql['dipl']=$this->rolesmodel->roleselect($piec);
.........
```

and if i use like this i get an error

```
.........
$sql[]=$this->rolesmodel->roleselect($piec);
.............
$sql['dipl']=$sql;
```

please help me with this issue

Comment: all you options have the same id "options". this wrongly wrong (and can cause some mess). Your best option is to remove the id from the "options" (or add a counter after them, or even the value).

Comment: error is->Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\newatmindia\application\views\roleschecked.php on line 9                                                               and the view file showing error is                                      <p>You Have selected the following persons</p>
<table border=2>
<tr>
<th>Sl.No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roles</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($dipl->result() as $row)
{?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row()->slNo?></td>
<td><?php echo $row()->name?></td>
<td><?php echo $row()->role?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing all checkboxes comma separated in a hidden field?

You can post them as straight as an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="123" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="543" />
```

in your controller you get the checked boxes as

```
$options = $this->input->post('options');
```

So your `tabledata()` function will look like this:

```
function tabledata(){

    $options = $this->input->post('options');
    $sql=array();
    foreach($options as $option){
        $sql[]=$this->rolesmodel->roleselect(intval($option));
    }

    // I'm not sure why you are assigning this back into the same array?!
    $sql['dipl']=$sql;
    $slr=$this->load->view('roleschecked',$sql,true);
    $value=array(
        'result'=>$slr
    );
    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

Please take a look at the commented line, where you assign all SQL statements back into the sql array, that looks odd to me.

Comment: the reason im writing all checkboxes comma separated in a hidden field is because i am getting these chkbox values from a table which i got  from model.the view page and model page is below

Comment: view page:                                                               <body>
<div id="rrol">
<table id="roletable" border=1>
<tr>
<th>SL.NO</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>ROLES</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($display->result() as $row)
{ 
?>
<tr id="rowId">
<td class="classID"><?php echo $row->slNo?>.</td>
<td class="classID" name="namz"><span><?php echo $row->name?></span></td>
<td class="classID"><?php echo $row->role?></td>

<td ><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="options" value="<?php echo $row->slNo?>"> </td>

</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
</div>

Comment: and the model is                                                          function selectroles()
 {
  $slct="SELECT * FROM dummyroles";
  $qry=$this->db->query($slct);
  return $qry;
 }

Comment: From the code in your comment it's still possible to use `option[]`. Also you are assigning the ID `option` several times which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like konsolenfreddy suggested - look at $sql['dipl'] assignment. When you first time assign values to $sql you have array of query results. Then again you assign $sql, but you do it on the same array - $sql, but to with index 'dipl'. What you get is array of arrays. Look at the example:

```
$aSql = array();
$aSql[] = 'foo';

$aSql['bar'] = $aSql;

var_dump($aSql);

result >>>

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["bar"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
}
```

Try to rename your inner $sql, like this:

```
// function tabledata()
$innerSql = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($pieces); $i++) { 
    $piec = $pieces[$i];
    $innerSql[] = $this->rolesmodel->roleselect($piec);
}

$sql['dipl'] = $innerSql;
```